# @Html.EditorFor targeting wrong property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am having razor view where i do edit my data.

Classes i do have are like this:

```
public class A
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        Value1 = "First";
        Value2 = 2;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
    public new CustomClass Value1 { get; set; }

    public B()
    {
        Value3 = 3;
        Value2 = new CustomClass();
    }
}
```

now when i call my `Razor View` i call it with this:

```
public IActionResult Edit()
{
    return View(new B());
}
```

Inside my `cshtml` code i have it setup like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Apply", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Value1);


    <label>Change value 3</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value3);

    <button class="button1">Apply!</button>
}
```

Now for some reason when i do apply changes, they do apply but with wrong `Value1` parameter.

I checked entrance of code and i saw `Value1` has good value, checked `/MyController/Apply` code and it has value null.

When i set breakpoint inside `cshtml` to see which value has `@HiddenFor(x => x.Value1)` i saw something strange to me and it is this (tag property in image is represented as `Value2` in above code):

[image]

So as you can see, for some reason razor somehow have both properties but one with `null` (which he get's inside view) and one with good values.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. The first is that you can not assign new CustomClass to `Value2`, since it is not overridden with operator `new` (the same way you did it with `Value1`).

Another is that you must at the top of the Razor page (cshtml) include your view model `@model <PathToViewModel>.B` before starting to use it.

There is working example:

**View model**

```
public class A
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        Value1 = "First";
        Value2 = 2;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int Value3 { get; set; }

    // This line overriding Value1 from the parent class A, so you can now assign it to a boolean (or CustomClass) value
    public new bool Value1 { get; set; }

    public B()
    {
        Value3 = 3;
        // Value2 = new CustomClass(); //Error since Value2 is declared to integer in the parent class

        // What you can do is to assign Value2 to a new integer value
        Value2 = 8;
    }
}
```

**Razor page**

```
@model Web.ViewModels.Account.B
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Value1);

    <p>Value 1: @Model.Value1</p> // prints: False
    <p>Value 2: @Model.Value2</p> // prints: 8
    <p>Value 2: @Model.Value3</p> // prints: 3

    <label>Change value 3</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value3);

    <button class="button1">Apply!</button>
}
```

Action in controller is correct.

**Post action:**

### [image: Post action]

> I also encourage you to use tag helpers instead of HTML helpers, you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1) more about it if you are using .NET Core. Down below is a similar example written with tag helpers.

```
@model Web.ViewModels.Account.B
<form asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Value1" />

    <label asp-for="Value3">Change value 3</label>
    <input asp-for="Value3" />

    <button class="button1">Apply!</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am getting the expected response.  I am using .Net 4.6 MVC. What does your POST action look like? 
[image]

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Apply(B b)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```